# WebDriver getText throws exceptions

Tags: java, exception, selenium, webdriver, gettext

Okay, I am completly clueless:
I have table on the page where every rows has CSS ID incremented by one. And I am searching the Auction ID in such table and matching it with the Auction I entered through previous Selenium test. So my code goes like this:

```
    int i = 0;
    Boolean stillHaveSomethingToSearch = true;
    Boolean foundit = false;

    while (stillHaveSomethingToSearch){
        idConstructor = "mainForm:aucPanelId:0:listOfAuctions:"+i;

        try{
            auctionRow = driver.findElement(By.id(idConstructor));
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e){
            stillHaveSomethingToSearch = false;
        }
        if (stillHaveSomethingToSearch) {
           foundAuctionID = auctionRow.getText();
            System.out.println("foundAuctionID = " + foundAuctionID);
           if (auctionID.equals(foundAuctionID)){
               stillHaveSomethingToSearch = false;
               foundit = true;
           }
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (foundit){
        auctionRow.click();
     }
```

Where "auctionID" is send to the method by previous test.

auctionRow is Webelement represented with two spans where the actual auctionID is stored

```
  <span id="mainForm:aucPanelId:0:listOfAuctions:0">116</span>
```

Whole row is clickable, so after i send the **click()** command, it will open me found auction

What is strange: The **auctionRow.getText();** throws an error.

If i change it to **getTagName()** function it will correctly return me "span"

How do I force it to provide me the text between two spans?

Stak Trace:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Build info: version: '2.0rc3', revision: 'unknown', time: '2011-06-21 23:22:02'
    System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.6.0_20'
    Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:105)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:213)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getText(RemoteWebElement.java:117)
        at com.deutscheboerse.testing.AuctionsPage.showAuctionID(AuctionsPage.java:63)
```

**SOLVED**
Ok, I found nice and easy (and shorter to code) workaround. Since I know that the Auction ID is in span element an I know what the ID should be, I am now searching by Xpath:

```
public AuctionTab showAuctionID(String auctionID){
    try{
     auctionRow = getRegulationUI().getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='"+auctionID+"']"));
    }catch (NoSuchElementException e){
        throw new NotFoundException("Auction ID "+ auctionID+ "was not found on first page");
    }
    auctionRow.click();
    return new AuctionTab(this);
    }
```

Comment: Glad you solved it, as a side note I would recommend you use the latest version of Selenium (2.16.1 last time I checked) from your stack trace it looks like you are using 2.0rc3. Sometimes strange errors can be bugs that have since been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this:

```
getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='"+auctionID+"']"));
```

I would try something like this:

```
By auctionList = By.xpath(".//span[contains(@id,'listOfAuctions')]"));
By containsTextWithId = By.xpath(".//span[contains(.,'" + id + "')]"));
By combinedLocator = new ByChained(auctionList, containsTextWithId);
```

Or some similar idea, depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getText(), in many occasions it's better to call getValue(). Using the getValue you might get a longer string, but the text you are expecting inside should be there.